# Use different theme for landing page in Magento

Tags: magento, themes

I have a them with the following folder structure:

```
landing/
├── confirmation.html
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── font-awesome.css
│   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   └── style.css
├── fonts
│   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
├── img
│   ├── bg-1.jpg
│   ├── bg-2.jpg
│   ├── bg-3.jpg
│   ├── bg-cta.jpg
│   ├── clients
│   │   ├── 1.png
│   │   ├── 2.png
│   │   ├── 3.png
│   │   ├── 4.png
│   │   ├── 5.png
│   │   └── 6.png
│   ├── transparent-dark.png
│   ├── transparent-light-2.png
│   └── transparent-light.png
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── html5shiv.js
│   ├── jquery-1.10.2.js
│   ├── jquery-1.10.2.min.js
│   ├── jquery.backstretch.min.js
│   ├── jquery.easing.min.js
│   ├── modernizr-2.6.2.min.js
│   ├── respond.min.js
│   └── scripts.js
└── subscribe.php
```

Which gives you a landing page [like this one](http://tarful.com/beta/zoi/).

I was hoping you could explain where should I put the files I was given in my magento installation and what settings should I change to make it the landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer to this one. You have to create new magento theme to get this result. To Create a new theme follow this guide.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package

And call your css and js using page.xml or local.xml

Then you have to manupulate the layout using xml and phtml's

Comment: I have followed the guide, now the theme appears in the **theme** selection. You say I should call the `css` and `js` using `page.xml`. How can I go about doing this? Where should I put the files in the theme folder?

Comment: in your theme Skin > front end > your package > your theme >
- css
- js
- images

add files to those folder..

copy default page.xml to your theme ex:-

D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\your package\your theme\layout

open page.xml

add js
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>

add css
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>